# csh alias with variable number of arguments

Tags: alias, csh

I would like to create a csh alias that performs one operation if invoked without arguments and a second operation if invoked with a single argument.  Does anyone know how to do this?  (Attempting to refer to an argument that wasn't passed triggers an error).

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a bit late but I just ran into needing something similar and hope it might still be relevant to somebody.

You can set the arguments as an array and query based on the size of the array:

```
alias testing 'set args_=(\!*); if ($#args_ > 0)  echo "this command has $#args_ arguments" endif'
```

Answer (score 3):

Aliases in tcsh are limited; for more advanced things, I've found that the best way is to `source` a (t)csh script, like so:

```
alias my-cmd 'source ~/.tcsh/my-cmd.tcsh'
```

And `~/.tcsh/my-cmd.tcsh` would contain something like:

```
if ( $1 != '' ) then
        echo "we have an argument: $1"
else
        echo "we don't have an argument"
endif
```

Example output:

```
% my-cmd
we don't have an argument
% my-cmd hello
we have an argument: hello
```

Now, it *may also* be possible to do this with just an alias, but this will be much more maintainable & cleaner in the long run, IMHO.

(I've assumed tcsh here since almost all, or perhaps even *all*, c shells are tcsh these days).

Comment: its beyond the scope of any shell alias mechanism ([tkc]sh) to process arguments. `[t]csh` doesn't do functions, so, @PhillipMFeldman this is your best bet. Either that, or switch to a shell that does support functions, which of course is the "right answer". I realize your work environment may not allow that, so if that is the case, use the above! Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter "*switch to a shell that does support functions, which of course is the "right answer*" ... Well no? Just because (t)csh doesn't support a certain feature or because you don't like it switching it the "right" answer...?

Comment: Hm... Sorry if I've offended. Not the intent. Maybe I should have said the O.P., either use this workable solution (which I have upvoted) OR switch to a shell that supports functions, as you seem to want features only supported in functions. Good luck to all!

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do - sorry I'm late to the party.

```csh
alias iftest    'if (\\!:0 != \\!:$) echo "Last arg="\\!:$;if (\\!:0 == \\!:$) echo "No args given."'
```

This merely checks whether the 0th argument (=the 'iftest' itself) and the last arguments are the same, and if they are, assumes there is no argument. This is, of course, not necessarily true, but hopefully works in praxis.

Comment: Won't this not work for edge cases like `my-command 1 2 3 4 3 2 1`?

Comment: Your two negations cancel, so the answer is yes - it will work, since 'my-command' is different from '1'. The case that won't work is      

    "my-command 1 2 3 4 3 2 my-command"

But I trust this case will not occur in nature ;-)

Comment: Nice one. You got me. Though I think that my usage of "won't" is colloquially understood in a general sense.  I.e. if you equate "not work" with "fail" (for clarity), I think anyone would respond to the question "Won't this fail for..." with "No". Technically, you're correct, both grammatically and with the shell example. Plus, my comment was stupid, as you already pointed out what I was erroneously trying to call attention to, so I'm just going to go into the corner and clutch my colloquialism point until you take that one away from me in your next response. 